# Unable to convert svn repository (without trunk) to git

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm trying to convert my svn repo to git, but I'm not having much success.
The repository in question does not have anything like a "trunk".
The layout is the following:

```
/home/svn/
      |--- /project1/
      |--- /project2/
      |--- /repos/project3/
```

And underneath those project folders are the files. No trunk, no branches, no nothing special. At the time that was all I needed, and now it's biting me in the ass.

I'm following this guide: http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git

When I run this command:

```
git svn clone svn+ssh://skerit@host.com/home/svn/repos/kiflea --no-metadata -A authors-transform.txt --stdlayout ~/kiflea
```

It says it has created an empty git repository... But I don't really want it to be empty.

I also have no idea what the following commands should look like, since my repository has a different layout.

Commands like `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/trunk` or `git config remote.bare.push 'refs/remotes/*:refs/heads/*'`

Comment: Remove --stdlayout Do you want to split it to 3 Git repositories?

Comment: That did it. I tried so many variations, so many commands, but removing the --stdlayout from this one didn't cross my mind. Answer the question so I can give you the bounty ;)

Comment: You should have just looked at the manual page (`git svn --help`). There is even a "BASIC EXAMPLES" section which unsurprisingly contains your exact case.

Comment: "There is no page about gitsvn"

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just remove `--stdlayout` option. It means trunk/branches/tags structure.